# for ComboBox, addActionListener -> actionPerformed?

Tags: java, codenameone

if I have

```
ComboBox box = b;
b.addActionListener(this);
```

shouldn't I expect `this.actionPerformed(event)` to be called
when  the combobox is operated?

I have a test frame with a few combo boxes, which seem to operate
normally, but no `actionPerformed` is ever called.   Perhaps the frame
itself needs to be armed in some way?

Comment: This should work, I'm guessing you might have more than one combo and might be referring to the wrong `actionPerformed` method. You can also follow the debugging process into the Codename One code itself by placing a listener in Codename One's `EventDispatcher` http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-debug-into-codename-one-source-modify-it-contribute-it-back.html

Comment: I use the old school form, where this class has an actionperformed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct answer.  I was using com.codename1.ui.Dialog as
the top level window.   I switched to using com.codename1.ui.Form
and now the actions are firing as expected.

Something in the environment constructed by Dialog (which extends Form)
is interfering with the event mechanism. Perhaps by design.

Comment: There is no such thing. However, a Dialog is a separate form and is blocking so your code to bind the event might have been placed after the show.

Comment: The event listeners are definitely installed, but you're correct that the significant difference is that Dialog.show() blocks but Form.show() does not.  Is there a writeup of the threading environment?  The curious thing (to me) is that the pulldown menus operate.  I would expect the event publishing to be done by the same thread.

Comment: Its `invokeAndBlock` which is how dialogs work in Swing/AWT/Codename One only we take it to the next level: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-1.html http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-2.html

Comment: It turns out a lot of my confusion resulted from the way I cannabalized your default projects to make test beds.  They apparently start in a critical thread, and if you end up blocking that thread some GUI things work strangely or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear and you didn't give it a proper title.

If you want to add ActionListener to a `ComboBox`, this is how you do it:

```
ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    }
});
```

Comment: That is essentially what I have done, but the actionperformed method is never called as the combobox is manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you just want to create a ComboBox from within a class that with be handling the action events. To do so I would suggest that the class inherits from ActionListener and override (use the @Override tag) the actionPerformed. Just Overriding the action perform is not enough if the class is not inheriting from ActionListener.

```
public class MyListener extends ActionListener {
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
         //code you want to execute when the event happens
    }
    public void methodCreatingComboBox(){
        ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
        b.addActionListener(this);
        //other stuffs
    }
}
```

that would work like a charm ! And you can use that same instance of MyListener for multiple events.